# JavaScript - Contenteditable bold option without execCommand

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable, wysiwyg

I want to create a simple WYSIWYG editor with contenteditable and a bold option. This used to be really easy to achieve using execCommand as can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41056605/contenteditable-div-with-bold-option).

Unfortunately execCommand is [now deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand).

My approach to achieve this without execCommand would be the following:

1. Get selection with [window.getSelection()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection)
2. Convert the selection to a text node on which I can set innerHTML and make sure it is a descendant of the contenteditable div
3. Do a simple transform of the innerHTML (e.g. `node.innerHTML = '<b>' + node.innerHTML + '</b>'`)

However, I am not sure how to achieve the second part. `window.getSelection().anchorNode` returns the correct node, but it won't let me set innerHTML or innerText on it.

Is this even possible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66059594/how-to-create-a-richtext-editor-in-html-js-without-document-execcommand

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the tags are not parsed in the only answer provided here. I don't want the user to see the HTML tags.

Comment: Although execCommand is deprecated you can still keep using it since there is no alternative. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70831583/1510309